# Combine 3 or 4 streams and edit in some of them

Tags: java, list, arraylist, split, stream

Its me again.
We have to program a Morse code converter,
I think I know about the theory and I also created my hash map with . 
And I want to try it with streams, does someone of you know how I combine streams and how I edit them then. Because I want to do it like

> read file by lines
>
> split in words
>
> split words in chars
>
> compare char with the key of the map and add the value to a String

I absolutely don’t want the whole code because I want to do most of it by myself,
But can someone explain it to me like

> 1st stream + split in the next stream 
>   This would be very helpful for me.

Regards, Lukas .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wish:
read file as stream of lines:

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("file-path"))) {
...
} catch ...
```

now you have the stream of lines - you need to split each of them  into words:
sth like: `line -> line.split("\\W+");` will do for each stream member (line) etc...

Comment: But can I do this in the same String

Comment: I meant *stream

Comment: sure I thought you want to do it yourself ;)
after
`stream.map(line -> line.split("\\W+"))`
you have 'stream of words' 
then you can map it again to get chars, etc...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you helped me a lot

Comment: BTW remember that you should not 'modify' stream elements - you can only 'collect'them at the end to get end result...

Comment: I imagine you want `flatMap(s -> Pattern.compile("\\W+").spiltAsStream(s))`.  It will be more readable if you create the Pattern before reading anything, then use `flatMap(pattern::splitAsStream)`.